# Is there something similar to Nokogiri for parsing Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, s-expression

Nokogiri is awesome. I can do things like `#css('.bla')` which will return the first matching element.

Right now we need to do some parsing of Ruby source code - finding all methods within a class etc. We're using the [ruby_parser](http://parsetree.rubyforge.org/ruby_parser/) gem, but all it does is comb your source code and spit out S-expressions. Is there anything like Nokogiri for these S-expressions which can do things like "return S-expression for first method found named 'foo'"?

Comment: do you really need to parse it ? As nash mentionned there is not much you cannot do with ruby metaprogramming.

Comment: Even if you could, that wouldn't tell you about any dynamically defined methods, for example of the kind `define_method("foo_#{bar}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is [Adam Sanderson's `SExpPath` library](https://GitHub.Com/AdamSanderson/SExp_Path/).

Answer (score 2):

Although I am accepting Jörg's answer because it is more complete, I ended up discovering something else which I ended up using. ruby_parser installs a dependent gem named [sexp_processor](https://github.com/seattlerb/sexp_processor) (it is in this gem where the `Sexp` class is actually defined). If you view the [class docs](http://rdoc.info/github/seattlerb/sexp_processor/33cd54ccac854ab10b30/Sexp) there are a few methods that will help with basic Ruby finders. Here's an example:

```
class Sexp
  def name          # convenience method
    self.sexp_body.first
  end
end    

# Print out all instance methods within classes. Beware - if "code" sexp itself
# is a class, it will NOT be included!
code = RubyParser.new.parse(IO.read('/src/file'))
code.each_of_type(:class){ |klass|
  klass.each_of_type(:defn){ |meth|
    puts meth.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about gem that you are looking for, but you can find all methods within a class using `instance_methods`:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end
end

irb(main):005:0> Foo.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods
=> [:bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the rubinius parser, it may help you to do what you want.