# Parse ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, ruby-ripper

I need help in one problem. I have a table with columns that contain some ruby code, like this: `self.org_premium = self.volume / 12 * 0.1492  self.billing_premium = self.subscriber_premium + self.org_premium` or `employment_level == 'P'` or `vol_life.save`. 
And now I want find methods in these strings, but some Rails methods, like `save` or `nil?` must be ignored.
I used Ripper, but his method `slice` return only 1 param.
Maybe you have some idea about this?

Comment: Somewhat-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379703/is-there-something-similar-to-nokogiri-for-parsing-ruby-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) to slice, e.g.:

```
$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > p Ripper.slice('def m(a) nil end', 'ident')
```

To see what events are available, just evaluate the constants it refers to in the doc: EVENTS which are further broken down into PARSER_EVENTS, and SCANNER_EVENTS.

```
$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > require 'ripper'
2.0.0p247 :002 > Ripper::EVENTS
 => [:BEGIN, :END, :alias, :alias_error, :aref, :aref_field, :arg_ambiguous, :arg_paren, :args_add, :args_add_block, :args_add_star, :args_new, :array, :assign, :assign_error, :assoc_new, :assoc_splat, :assoclist_from_args, :bare_assoc_hash, :begin, :binary, :block_var, :block_var_add_block, :block_var_add_star, :blockarg, :bodystmt, :brace_block, :break, :call, :case, :class, :class_name_error, :command, :command_call, :const_path_field, :const_path_ref, :const_ref, :def, :defined, :defs, :do_block, :dot2, :dot3, :dyna_symbol, :else, :elsif, :ensure, :excessed_comma, :fcall, :field, :for, :hash, :if, :if_mod, :ifop, :lambda, :magic_comment, :massign, :method_add_arg, :method_add_block, :mlhs_add, :mlhs_add_star, :mlhs_new, :mlhs_paren, :module, :mrhs_add, :mrhs_add_star, :mrhs_new, :mrhs_new_from_args, :next, :opassign, :operator_ambiguous, :param_error, :params, :paren, :parse_error, :program, :qsymbols_add, :qsymbols_new, :qwords_add, :qwords_new, :redo, :regexp_add, :regexp_literal, :regexp_new, :rescue, :rescue_mod, :rest_param, :retry, :return, :return0, :sclass, :stmts_add, :stmts_new, :string_add, :string_concat, :string_content, :string_dvar, :string_embexpr, :string_literal, :super, :symbol, :symbol_literal, :symbols_add, :symbols_new, :top_const_field, :top_const_ref, :unary, :undef, :unless, :unless_mod, :until, :until_mod, :var_alias, :var_field, :var_ref, :vcall, :void_stmt, :when, :while, :while_mod, :word_add, :word_new, :words_add, :words_new, :xstring_add, :xstring_literal, :xstring_new, :yield, :yield0, :zsuper, :CHAR, :__end__, :backref, :backtick, :comma, :comment, :const, :cvar, :embdoc, :embdoc_beg, :embdoc_end, :embexpr_beg, :embexpr_end, :embvar, :float, :gvar, :heredoc_beg, :heredoc_end, :ident, :ignored_nl, :int, :ivar, :kw, :label, :lbrace, :lbracket, :lparen, :nl, :op, :period, :qsymbols_beg, :qwords_beg, :rbrace, :rbracket, :regexp_beg, :regexp_end, :rparen, :semicolon, :sp, :symbeg, :symbols_beg, :tlambda, :tlambeg, :tstring_beg, :tstring_content, :tstring_end, :words_beg, :words_sep]
2.0.0p247 :009 > Ripper::PARSER_EVENTS
 => [:BEGIN, :END, :alias, :alias_error, :aref, :aref_field, :arg_ambiguous, :arg_paren, :args_add, :args_add_block, :args_add_star, :args_new, :array, :assign, :assign_error, :assoc_new, :assoc_splat, :assoclist_from_args, :bare_assoc_hash, :begin, :binary, :block_var, :block_var_add_block, :block_var_add_star, :blockarg, :bodystmt, :brace_block, :break, :call, :case, :class, :class_name_error, :command, :command_call, :const_path_field, :const_path_ref, :const_ref, :def, :defined, :defs, :do_block, :dot2, :dot3, :dyna_symbol, :else, :elsif, :ensure, :excessed_comma, :fcall, :field, :for, :hash, :if, :if_mod, :ifop, :lambda, :magic_comment, :massign, :method_add_arg, :method_add_block, :mlhs_add, :mlhs_add_star, :mlhs_new, :mlhs_paren, :module, :mrhs_add, :mrhs_add_star, :mrhs_new, :mrhs_new_from_args, :next, :opassign, :operator_ambiguous, :param_error, :params, :paren, :parse_error, :program, :qsymbols_add, :qsymbols_new, :qwords_add, :qwords_new, :redo, :regexp_add, :regexp_literal, :regexp_new, :rescue, :rescue_mod, :rest_param, :retry, :return, :return0, :sclass, :stmts_add, :stmts_new, :string_add, :string_concat, :string_content, :string_dvar, :string_embexpr, :string_literal, :super, :symbol, :symbol_literal, :symbols_add, :symbols_new, :top_const_field, :top_const_ref, :unary, :undef, :unless, :unless_mod, :until, :until_mod, :var_alias, :var_field, :var_ref, :vcall, :void_stmt, :when, :while, :while_mod, :word_add, :word_new, :words_add, :words_new, :xstring_add, :xstring_literal, :xstring_new, :yield, :yield0, :zsuper] 
2.0.0p247 :010 > Ripper::SCANNER_EVENTS
 => [:CHAR, :__end__, :backref, :backtick, :comma, :comment, :const, :cvar, :embdoc, :embdoc_beg, :embdoc_end, :embexpr_beg, :embexpr_end, :embvar, :float, :gvar, :heredoc_beg, :heredoc_end, :ident, :ignored_nl, :int, :ivar, :kw, :label, :lbrace, :lbracket, :lparen, :nl, :op, :period, :qsymbols_beg, :qwords_beg, :rbrace, :rbracket, :regexp_beg, :regexp_end, :rparen, :semicolon, :sp, :symbeg, :symbols_beg, :tlambda, :tlambeg, :tstring_beg, :tstring_content, :tstring_end, :words_beg, :words_sep]
```

The 'ident' is an event for method name definition in this case, and that event isn't really equivalent to a method that is called in the code.

I'm not sure that Ripper would be the easiest way to parse out method names that are used. In addition, the ability for Ruby to handle calls handled by `method_missing` really make it difficult to see what could be interpreted.

Like I said in the comments, there are several other ways to parse methods you might look into.

You could even just make something similar with string operations/checking available methods, e.g.

```
class A
  IGNORE = %w{save nil?}

  def find_possible_methods(s)
    s.split(/[\-\ ,\.\(\)\{\}\[\]]/).reject{|c| c =~ /[0-9\*\-\/\+\%\=\~].*/ || c.empty? || IGNORE.include?(c)}
  end

  def find_implemented_methods(s)
    (s.split(/[\-\ ,\.\(\)\{\}\[\]]/) & (methods + private_methods).collect(&:to_s)).reject{|c| IGNORE.include?(c)}
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
a = A.new
 => #<A:0x007facb9a94be8> 
a.find_possible_methods 'self.org_premium = self.volume / 12 * 0.1492 self.billing_premium = self.subscriber_premium + self.org_premium'
 => ["self", "org_premium", "self", "volume", "self", "billing_premium", "self", "subscriber_premium", "self", "org_premium"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution isn't help me. I need a solution like this: https://github.com/michaeledgar/object_regex. Original method search from start to one match, but I want find all matches. Author wants extract only comments and this gem doesn't work for methods. Maybe you know how do this?

Comment: Please clarify in the question exactly what you are looking for. Could look at the following, but all are not completely up-to-date: [ruby_parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser), [SExp_Path](https://github.com/AdamSanderson/SExp_Path/), [this post](http://programmingisterrible.com/post/42432568185/how-to-parse-ruby), [ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html), [ripper-plus](https://github.com/michaeledgar/ripper-plus), [laser](https://github.com/michaeledgar/laser)

Comment: Also there are ways to determine methods as they are executed at runtime, like: [TracePoint](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html) and [set_trace_func](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/set_trace_func). And [tracer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html) if you wanted to see code lines that are executed. But, I don't think you are looking for that?

Comment: Added a little more info about Ripper. Basically, the `slice` method is like a shortcut to parse and gather events that occurred during the parsing, and use Ripper's constants to get a list of those available events.

Comment: I think that I have only two possible solutions using Ripper:
1) use rules, when try to parse with method lex;
2) and create a method that will use the slice with the specified pattern and remove it from the string with ruby code.
But I can't find documentation on creating patterns for this method.
Tnaks for help.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck. I think if you could explain specifically the goal of what you are trying to do in the question itself, you might get more help. I.e. what are you going to do once you have the list of methods? Possibly you could do something else entirely that would be a better way to achieve your goal.