# How do I extract just a specific portion of a code snippet from multiple files, that may be different in different files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, ruby-on-rails-5

So what I am doing is iterating over various versions of snippet of code (for e.g. [Associations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/17136c201320e9a041f2d98eacd299f2ce3eb154/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb) in Rails).

What I want to do is just extract one snippet of the code, for example the [has_many](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/db045dbbf60b53dbe013ef25554fd013baf88134/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L179-L216) method:

```
  def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
    reflection = Builder::HasMany.build(self, name, scope, options, &extension)
    Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
  end
```

At first I was thinking of just searching this entire file for the string `def has_many` and then saving everything between that string and `end`. The obvious issue with this, is that different versions of this file can have multiple `end` strings within the method.

For instance, whatever I come up with for the above snippet, should also work for [this one too](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/db045dbbf60b53dbe013ef25554fd013baf88134/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L179-L216):

```
  def has_many(association_id, options = {})
    validate_options([ :foreign_key, :class_name, :exclusively_dependent, :dependent, :conditions, :order, :finder_sql ], options.keys)
    association_name, association_class_name, association_class_primary_key_name =
          associate_identification(association_id, options[:class_name], options[:foreign_key])

    require_association_class(association_class_name)

    if options[:dependent] and options[:exclusively_dependent]
      raise ArgumentError, ':dependent and :exclusively_dependent are mutually exclusive options.  You may specify one or the other.' # ' ruby-mode
    elsif options[:dependent]
      module_eval "before_destroy '#{association_name}.each { |o| o.destroy }'"
    elsif options[:exclusively_dependent]
      module_eval "before_destroy { |record| #{association_class_name}.delete_all(%(#{association_class_primary_key_name} = '\#{record.id}')) }"
    end

    define_method(association_name) do |*params|
      force_reload = params.first unless params.empty?
      association = instance_variable_get("@#{association_name}")
      if association.nil?
        association = HasManyAssociation.new(self,
          association_name, association_class_name,
          association_class_primary_key_name, options)
        instance_variable_set("@#{association_name}", association)
      end
      association.reload if force_reload
      association
    end

    # deprecated api
    deprecated_collection_count_method(association_name)
    deprecated_add_association_relation(association_name)
    deprecated_remove_association_relation(association_name)
    deprecated_has_collection_method(association_name)
    deprecated_find_in_collection_method(association_name)
    deprecated_find_all_in_collection_method(association_name)
    deprecated_create_method(association_name)
    deprecated_build_method(association_name)
  end
```

Assuming that each value is stored as `text` in some column in my db.

How do I approach this, using Ruby's string methods or should I be approaching this another way?

**Edit 1**

Please note that this question relates specifically to string manipulation via using a Regex, without a parser.

Comment: If you can rely on indentation, check http://rubular.com/r/54KgpTRo8C ... Notice though, it could break with multine strings, HEREDOC, %{ }, etc.

Comment: @Mariano Holy crap. That looks awesome. Can you add it as an answer, and explain the different elements. It may not be perfect, but it's an awesome start!

Comment: Sure, but I'd wait for someone to recommend a code parser. That's the way it should be done (I'm not familiar with ruby parsers). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451326/parse-ruby-code for example

Comment: Oh wow...never knew about parsers. Interesting. I just found an interesting gem - https://github.com/whitequark/parser. Thanks for the hat tip. Either way, I love your RegEx. It looks awesome.

Comment: @Mariano Go ahead and answer your question, assuming no parser. I have asked another question, that is focused specifically on using the parser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630553/how-do-i-use-the-parser-gem-to-extract-this-code-snippet-i-want -- but I really like your answer here so I would love to document it properly.

Comment: @Mariano Awesome. Question updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, this should be done with a parser like [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html).

---

However, to answer if it can be done with string methods, I will match the syntax with a regex, provided:

- You can rely on indentation i.e. the string has the exact same characters before `"def"` and before `"end"`.
- There are no multiline strings in between that could simulate an `"end"` with the same indentation. That includes multine strings, HEREDOC, %{ }, etc.

---

**Code**

```ruby
regex = /^
        (\s*)              # matches the indentation (we'll backreference later)
        def\ +has_many\b   # literal "def has_many" with a word boundary
        (?:.*+\n)*?        # match whole lines - as few as possible
        \1                 # matches the same indentation as the def line
        end\b              # literal "end"
        /x

subject = %q|
  def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
      if association.nil?
        instance_variable_set("@#{association_name}", association)
      end
  end|


#Print matched text
puts subject.to_enum(:scan,regex).map {$&}
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/GFKTtW)</kbd>

The regex relies on:

1. Capturing the whitespace (indentation) with the group `(\s*)`,
2. followed by the literal `def has_many`.
3. It then consumes as few lines as it can with `(?:.*+\n)*?`.
   Notice that `.*+\n` matches a whole line
   and `(?:`..`)*?` repeats it 0 or more times. Also, the last `?` makes the repetition **[lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)** (as few as possible).
   It will consume lines until it matches the following condition...
4. `\1` is a **[backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)**, storing the text matched in **(1)**, i.e. the exact same indentation as the first line.
5. Followed by `end` obviously.

Test in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/bTT43x7HAF)

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks much!